# Sampling points uniformly inside a sphere; marginal distribution of the dimensions

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling

I was asked a question on how to uniform sample points inside a sphere, and what is the marginal distribution of one dimension.

The most obvious solution that came to me was rejection sampling. Simply consider a hypercube around the sphere. Say the radius of the sphere is $R$, hence the side lengths of the cube is $2R$. Then we can sample $X,Y,Z \in U(-R, R)$.

We reject all the points such that $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2+Z^2} > R$, and the remaining points that we accept should be uniformly distributed within the sphere.

I'm not sure if there's a better approach analogous to the gaussian sampling method for points on the *surface* of a sphere. But anyways, the second question asked me what is the marginal distribution of each dimension.

At first, I thought isn't the marginal distribution simply $U(-R, R)$, but then I realized that this is incorrect. I think the distribution we're looking for is a conditional distribution given the point is validly inside the sphere.

While we sampled $X,Y,Z$ from a uniform distribution, we rejected samples as well, and the accepted sample's dimensions are no longer uniformly distributed. This is easier to see in 2-D, where if you consider a circle, where center is at $X=Y=0$, we will see that the $X,Y$ values close to the center will have a higher frequency of occurring, because the other dimension isn't as constrained. For example, consider $X=0$, any value of $Y \sim U(-R,R)$ will be inside the circle. But if say $X = 0.5$, then $Y$'s possible values are reduced to the interval $[-\sqrt{R^2 - 0.5^2}, \sqrt{R^2 - 0.5^2}]$.

So my inclination now is that each dimension is some type of symmetrically distributed pdf about the center, with the peak pdf value occurring at the center. I want to say that it's a gaussian distribution,  but the gaussian distribution extends to $\pm \infty$, whereas this pdf we're looking for is bounded by $\pm R$.

As somewhat of an aside, and maybe relevant to solving this question (?), is there a way to figure out the joint pdf of $X,Y,Z$?

Comment: The marginal distribution of any given dimension (say, $X$) is proportional to the cross-sectional area at coordinate $X = x$.  That is, $f_X(x) = \frac34(1-x^2)$ for $|x| \leq 1$; else it equals $0$.

Comment: The joint distribution of $X, Y, Z$ is uniform over the volume of the sphere.  That is, $f_{X, Y, Z}(x, y, z) = \frac{3}{4\pi}$ if $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1$; else it equals $0$.

Comment: (Sorry, those are for the unit sphere.  You can scale accordingly for a sphere of radius $R$.)

Comment: @BrianTung I don't think I see how $f_X(x) = \frac{3}{4}(1-x^2)$ arrived from proportionality to the cross-sectional area, could you please expand on this? And for the dimension $X$, what plane does the cross sectional area you're referring to lie in?

Comment: The probability density at $X = x$ (provided $-1 \leq x \leq 1$) is proportional to the cross-sectional area of the sphere for that value of $x$.  For instance, if $x = 0.8$, the cross section is a circle of radius $\sqrt{1-0.8^2} = \sqrt{1-0.64} = \sqrt{0.36} = 0.6$.  This cross section has an area of $\pi(0.6)^2 = 0.36\pi$.  More generally, for any value of $x$, $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, the cross section has area $\pi(\sqrt{1-x^2})^2 = \pi(1-x^2)$.  We therefore know that $f_X(x) = k(1-x^2)$.  To determine $k$, we integrate $f_X$ from $x = -1$ to $1$, and find for what $k$ it integrates to $1$.

Comment: @BrianTung In general, if you have a some n-dimensional region (e.g., plane, cube, sphere, etc..) where points are uniformly distributed inside it. Is the joint pdf of the n dimensions always the inverse of the n-dimensional area (not sure what generic name of the n-dimensional enclosure is called beyond n > 3)?